# Is there any way to change the default file manager in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I replace default Windows Explorer with an alternative one, say Q-Dir?](https://superuser.com/questions/241442/how-would-i-replace-default-windows-explorer-with-an-alternative-one-say-q-dir)

I want to change the default file manager from Windows Explorer to Explorer XP. Is this possible? If the answer is "yes", how can I do this?

Comment: What don't you like about W7 file manager?

Answer (score 3):

Er, if you're asking about [ExplorerXP](http://www.explorerxp.com) then yes, it works fine. If you're are asking about Windows Explorer, from XP's version then `Phoshi` is correct.
I guess to make it the default manager is to change the shell from explorer to explorerxp ?

Comment: Hang on, he meant ExplorerXP? Well I'm wrong, then!

Comment: Well he says "Default File Manager From Windows Explorer to Explorer XP" so I'm assuming he wants ExplorerXP. Either ways, he stands to gain.

Comment: I'm not really "in" the whole Explorer replacement scene, so had forgotten about ExplorerXP's existence. Sorry, ExplorerXp guys! :(

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The XP version of explorer won't run on 7, but why would you want it to?
If you have problems with the 7 one, it'd be much easier to either work around, or fix them, than use XP's file manager. If you really hate the new one, though, there are alternatives, such as [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com).

**Edit:**If you meant ExplorerXP, as detailed in [Sathya](https://superuser.com/questions/70826/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-default-file-manager-in-win7/70849#70849)'s answer, then **Yes, yes you can**.

Comment: Note that explorer.exe manages also the Desktop. If you replaced it with another file manager, you loose the Desktop, unless the replacement also manages one on its own.

Comment: Nah, you can use a replacement file manager without changing the shell, and vice versa. Takes a bit of trickery, but it's more than possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the entire shell, there are a few custom shells for windows. A good windows shell is the Cairo Shell. These replace the entire windows shell and give you an entire new user interface.

Cairo Shell:
[www.cairoshell.com](http://www.cairoshell.com/)

This doesn't change your operating system, but it does make it look entirely different. Cairo Shell is comparable to Gnome or KDE on linux distributions.

Comment: CairoShell it's far from being ready and what i've seen so far didn't leave much of an impression.

Comment: True thing. I think it would be a great replacement in windows xp, but windows 7 had this dockbar which I find alot handier. That's one thing I miss in ubuntu; DockbarX isn't close to the windows 7 taskbar.

Comment: I like Emerge Desktop, for the sheer simplicity and modularity. Cairo left me a bit disappointed, especially seeing as I've been waiting for the public alpha for, what? A year now? More?

Answer (score 0):

Give Q-Dir a try, it can be configured as a single pane file manager if you wish.

http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir

.

Frequently asked questions about Q-Dir

http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Q-DIR&faq=0