# How would I replace default Windows Explorer with an alternative one, say Q-Dir?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I would like to re-map existing shortcuts, right-clicks, etc so Q-Dir is opened instead of default Windows Explorer.

short of renaming ``explorer.exe in Windows folder - are there any settings I need to look at? 
maybe in Registry somewhere?

Comment: if the solution provided worked, please make sure to mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run regedit.exe, go to 
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]`
find "shell" string and change value from explorer.exe on Q-dir with full path, then reboot.

Comment: While this works, it also limits normal shell functionality for me. Therefore, I prefer replacing just the explorer shortcut instead on windows 10 and above

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called [InstantSheller](https://www.gameex.com/instant-sheller-0-9/) that can start programs instead of the Windows shell.

[image]

It does essentially what Ratin's answer does in the registry, with a few more UI options.

I use it to boot my HTPC's software, hiding the Windows boot logo, login screen and explorer. You can revert the changes by opening the application again and clicking undo.

Comment: The link to the vendor is dead.

Comment: @IInspectable updated!

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a full explorer replacement, I prefer just replacing the launch target of the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> shortcut following the approach for Windows 10 / 11 described [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/winkey-e-shortcut-target-change/). This ensures the normal shell functionality (e.g. Start Menu, task bar, system tray etc. is left untouched)

For my portable version of Q-Dir a registry file looks like this

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}]
@=""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\opennewwindow]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{52205fd8-5dfb-447d-801a-d0b52f2e83e1}\shell\opennewwindow\command]
@="C:\\Users\\[username]\\Downloads\\Q-DirPortable\\App\\Q-Dir\\Q-Dir_x64.exe"
"DelegateExecute"=""
```

Replace `C:\\Users\\[username]\\Downloads\\Q-DirPortable\\App\\Q-Dir\\Q-Dir_x64.exe` with your Q-Dir installation path above (and use `\\` to escape `\` correctly as shown). Then import the file into the registry (e.g. via double-clicking it in Explorer + confirming the registry import).

After that Q-Dir will launch when <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is being pressed instead of Explorer

Answer (score 0):

There is a way! I discovered it recently, steps:

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\open\command`

Inside that key delete `DelegateExecute` and rename the `Default` to the proper location of the file manager(here is Dolphin from KDE in my case), like:

```
"C:\PATH\dolphin-22.12.2-1828\bin\dolphin.exe" %1
```

- The `%1` is important (for the arguments)

This will:

- Evertytime you open a folder it will open with Dolphin at that location

> PS: for Dolphin there are more tweaks necessary since you will need to create `*.desktop` for shortcuts, and change the default location to "default" for the above to work.

Also add @kf06925 answer so everything will be nice and smooth!