# changing "explorer" program, now cannot use computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In registry, I've tried to change "explorer" to "Directory Opus", as per instructions here : [How would I replace default Windows Explorer with an alternative one, say Q-Dir?](https://superuser.com/questions/241442/how-would-i-replace-default-windows-explorer-with-an-alternative-one-say-q-dir)

But it doesn't work. Now I have a black screen. Cannot go back to "explorer.exe".

How can I go into the registry now to revert back to "explorer.exe" ?

I have Windows 10.

On reboot, "Directory Opus" opened. I could search for "regedit.exe", and set back to "explorer.exe".

But when I reboot, it still says "directory opus" in registry !

Comment: Not an answer, unfortunately, but in general be very careful about any "tips" that involve editing the registry. Especially ones that are out-of-date or involve a different Windows version.

Comment: well, you can use an install disk to restore to a prior restore point, or you could try the offline password and registery editor: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/gr/offlinentpwed.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With "Directory Opus", I searched for msconfig. I did a Safe boot.

Then the registry showed me "explorer.exe".

After a normal boot, "explorer" is back.

Answer (score 0):

For Directory Opus, you can select a safer approach to replace explorer via
`Settings -> Preferences -> Explorer Replacement`

[image: Explorer Replacement]

This will leave the normal explorer.exe configured as shell and still allow you to run Opus instead of Explorer for most operations including pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>